# Unobtrusive Javascript Validation with MVC 3, is preventing me validating form manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

For 90% of my site the standard MVC annotation with client script method is working a treat. But I have a form on the site that is quite complicated with multiple instances of dynamic form content dependant on answers to questions etc.

If I have the unobtrusive script included on the page, it's capturing the form submit and not allowing my custom jquery validate to validate the form.

I don't really want to refactor the site to have a seperate layout to remove the script when it's not needed. I wondered if there was an easy way to give control back to my custom validate script.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you can disable client side validation like this

```
Html.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = false
```

Comment: Excellent I'll try that in a bit.